# Podfile with iOS and OSX Support

Tags: ios, macos, cocoapods

I'm trying to setup CocoaPods with a legacy project which has both iOS and a OSX targets.

If, at the top of my Podfile, I specify:

```
platform :osx, '10.9'
```

and, as an example, specify a pod like CorePlot:

```
pod 'CorePlot'
```

Then, after a `pod update`, I see Mac specific sources in my Pods directory:

```
Pods/CorePlot/framework/MacOnly
```

which is okay, except that if I were to specify `:ios` as the `platform` then I see:

```
Pods/CorePlot/framework/iPhoneOnly
```

and I *do not* see the `MacOnly` directory.

CorePlot's podspec specifies these directories based on the platform, which is why they are showing up differently based on the platform I select. However, I would like to be able to have my Podfile work for my iOS and OSX targets.

I continued and thought perhaps I could specify the platform based on the target in my project, and omit the top level platform declaration:

```
target "OSX" do
  platform :osx, '10.9'
end

target "iOS" do
  platform :ios, '7.0'
end
```

However, once I again do a `pod update` now I get a version compatibility error:

> [!] The platform of the target `Pods` (OS X ) is not compatible with `CorePlot (1.5.1)` which has a minimum requirement of iOS 3.1.3 - OS X 10.5."

Which would seem to indicate that CocoaPods is not recognizing the version information in my target block.

And, if I add a platform to the top level, in addition to the target specific platform, I then get only the code for whichever platform the top level platform indicated.

Am I forced to have two separate projects? One for iOS and one for Mac OS X, or is there a way to do this?

Many thanks,

Levi

```
   CocoaPods : 0.31.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
    RubyGems : 2.0.3
        Host : Mac OS X 10.9.2 (13C64)
       Xcode : 5.1.1 (5B1008)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ bf6ff4b23c2e8b9e5fe5840eddfc3bad122eb932
```

Comment: Filed as an issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2043

Answer (score 14):

Based on https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2043#issuecomment-59295308

```
def import_pods
    pod 'CorePlot'
end

target :ios do
    platform :ios, '7.0'
    import_pods
end

target :osx do
    platform :osx, '10.9'
    import_pods
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `abstract_target`s to separate pods by platform:

```
use_frameworks!

# Common pods
pod ...

abstract_target 'Mobile' do
  
  platform :ios, '13.0'
  
  # Common pods for mobile
  pod ...
  
  target 'My iOS App' do
    
    # Target specific pods
    pod ...
    
  end
  
end

abstract_target 'Mac' do
  
  platform :osx, '11.0'

  # Common Mac pods
  pod ...
  
  target 'My Mac App' do

  # Target specific pods
    
  end
  
end
```

Comment: What is the difference between abstract_target and target?

Comment: @JThora abstract targets don't have a "real" target counterpart in the Xcode project. They just serve to create logic groups in the Podfile.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense and clears up some things I've seen before.